# simple way to use bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I wrote a text using :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report},
 and
\begin{thebibliography}{99}.
```

Now I have to change and use ''bibtex''. I am completely unfamiliar with bibtex, What is a simple way that I can change it? ( what userpakage should I add ,... )

Comment: Commenting instead of answering since it is not self contained. I suggest a look at the fourth chapter of the `latex primer` book. https://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/tutorials/ltxprimer-1.0.pdf  Basically you need to convert all the `bibitems` to another format and put them in a different file (`*.bib`). Run latex on the main file once, bibtex once and latex again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a bibliography database (a file with extension `.bib`), say `mybiblio.bib`. Its contents will be the same as your `\bibitem`s, in a normalised form. I suggest to use a dedicated tool for this task, such as `JabRef`, in which you only have to fill the relevant fields.

This being done, you have to tell latex to incorporate this bibliography in your document. You have two slightly different ways, according to whether you use `biblatex` or not.

- The ‘old way’: choose a bibliography style in your preamble, e.g. `\bibliographystyle{plain}`; add `\nocite{*}` if you want *all* bibliography items to be printed (even those you do not cite). In your document, write `\bibliography{mybiblio}` where you want the bibliography to appear.
- the ‘new way’: with biblatex, write in your preamble `\usepackage[options]{biblatex}`. Then, you have to declare the .bib file in the preamble, with `\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}`  (extension required).
  In the body of the document, add the command `\printbibliography` where you you want it.

Note that with `biblatex`, you can use two engines for the bibliography: `bibtex` or the more recent (and powerful) `biber`. For `bibtex` the `.bib` files have to be `ascii`-encoded, whereas `biber` understands `utf8`.

To obtain the bibliography in your .pdf, you'll follow the cycle:

`(pdf)latex > bibtex or biber > (pdf)latex (twice)`.

Comment: You might want to mention that for journal submissions, `biblatex` most likely isn't  allowed.